# Simple function for pairs disjoints sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that every simple function we can write as $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k 1_{A_k}(x)$$

where $A_k$ are pairs disjoints sets.

My attempt:

Let $B_1,...,B_n$ be any sets. We define $A_n$ sets as:

$$A_1 = B_1 \\ A_n = B_n \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1} B_k$$.

These sets are disjoints. Furthermore $$ \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} B_k = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k$$

I think that now I have to show that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k 1_{A_k}(x) = \sum_{l=1}^{m} b_l 1_{B_l}(x)$$

How to show it - I don't have any idea. Could you help me? Maybe exsists better and easier way to get this proof?

Comment: A simple function is one that takes finitely many values $\{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\}$, so just define $A_j := f^{-1}(\{y_j\})$, and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, but how can it help me? Of course we have $$ \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} f^{-1} \left[ \left\{ y_j \right\} \right] = f^{-1} \left[ \left\{ y_1,...,y_n\right\} \right] $$ but what is the next step?

Comment: Try showing that $f = \sum y_j \chi_{A_j}$

Comment: But it is definition of $f$, is it not? Why I have to prove it?